# how to use boostrap datepicker in apache wicket?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, wicket-6

am try to modify the ui design of wicket datepicker.am not able to solve that problem.

```
<p class="input-group" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <input type="text" wicket:id="endDate" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>




form.add(new DateTextField("endDate"));
```

the date has been stored. but edit time its not showing

Comment: Can you check once: http://wb.agilecoders.de/demo/datepicker

Comment: i got that code in github. but it's not working in my machine.

Comment: which error you are getting ?

Comment: if i am import via maven project that time got error. blueprint.xml and wicket.xml this two file

Comment: then hopefully they are not properly imported or any dependencies are not injected correctly ? check any errors you found in those two files.

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Referenced file contains errors (http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd). For more information, right click 
  on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."
 - Start tag of element <blueprint>                                                                                          this error coming

Comment: Wicket-Bootstrap neither requires, nor uses OSGi. So the error with blueprint.xsd is something in your application. Additionally it seems you use Angular.js. How do you integrate it with Wicket?

Comment: @Rajeshkannan Ramakrishnan, this is because of your xsd infomration error or any version of it or else could be any build path or any jar version, etc. this one I can say now.

Comment: angularjs ui bootstrap datepicker not taking default value. that problem am facing. it showing today date default. date is coming form database it's not showing